# How did we get onto/into the subject

Tags: phrase-meaning

Do both sentences below share the same meaning or are they interchangeable?

(1) How did we get onto this subject?
(2) How did we get into this subject?

Comment: Both are fine, it's just a matter of whether you're thinking of the abstract referent *(**this subject**)* in terms of a ***surface metaphor*** (ONTO or ON TO) or a ***container metaphor*** (INTO). [Most people choose the former.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=got+onto+the+subject%2Cgot+on+to+the+subject%2Cgot+into+the+subject&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgot%20onto%20the%20subject%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgot%20on%20to%20the%20subject%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgot%20into%20the%20subject%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Note that the surface metaphor can more naturally carry the sense of *at some **distance** [from where we are now]*, as in *We'll start by reviewing what you already know, before we move on to differential calculus*. Whereas the *container* metaphor is better if you want to extend and amplify the sense of *a more **thorough** examination*, as in *We'll go **deeper** into differential calculus next term.*